# How to pass in nullable INT type to INSERT INTO parameter

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, insert-into

I need to pass in a nullable int type (passed in as an OPTIONAL param, sometimes it's defined, sometimes it's not...) into an INSERT INTO command in C# via paramters.  Below is a screenshot of my code.

Here is the offending line of code, truncated for clarity...

```
public void WriteCustomColumns(... int? parentPlacementId = null)
{
    command.Parameters["@ParentPlacementId"].Value = (parentPlacementId == null ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null.Value : parentPlacementId);
```

**Here is the screenshot of the error...**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to not use the conditional operator

```
SqlParameter p = command.Parameters.Add("@ParentPlacementId", SqlDbType.BigInt);
if(parentPlacementId.HasValue) 
     p.Value = parentPlacementId; 
else 
     p.Value = DBNull.Value;
```

As a possible alternative (not recommended)

```
command.Parameters["@ParentPlacementId"].Value = 
     (parentPlacementId.HasValue ? (object)parentPlacementId.Value : (object)DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is failing because `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null` throws `SqlNullValueException` when you try to access `.Value`.

Use just `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null`.

[Handling Null Values in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 command.Parameters["@ParentPlacementId"].Value = parentPlacementId.HasValue ? parentPlacementId.Value : System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null.Value;
```

Reference Microsoft's 
[Using Nullable Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

Comment: I dont' know why.. But this is giving the same error:  "Cannot called on NULL values..."  Using if-else as suggested by @Steve works.

Comment: Sorry KKKKKKKK, I thought it was a simple int and didn't see BigInt. Kudos to @Steve for finding a fix for you.